# I want to create python script file: i am new to it

Tags: python

I want to create python script file and how it is run with command line.

like this:
file include this cording part:
include to numbers as command line param and print the sum of the numbers.

C:\python32\python.exe some.py 1 2

result will be :
The sum is 3

I want to do above scenario in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two numbers are integer:

```
import sys
print(int(sys.argv[1]) + int(sys.argv[2]))
```

or, more generally:

```
import sys
print(sum(map(int, sys.argv[1:])))
```

Comment: @Elshan a personal thanks is always nice (but not required), but you'll also have a little tick-box next to this answer that means accept - since this solved your question, use that - that'll be thanks again!